# Unable to find a suitable output format for 'libfdk_aac' libfdk_aac: Invalid argument

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to run this command in Windows 10. The script ran fine with 2 60mb samples. But now trying to run it on the full video, I'm getting this error: `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'libfdk_aac' libfdk_aac: Invalid argument`

This is the command I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -i 300roae.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -crf 28 -x265-params -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -b:a 72k C:\Users\hifim\Videos\300roae.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening because the `-x265-params` option is missing the required parameter. Instead of a real parameter to pass to libx265, it is swallowing the audio codec option. See [Passing Options](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265#PassingOptions) in FFmpeg's "H.265/HEVC Video Encoding Guide".

Comment: yes i see the mistake now..I had this in there before -x265-params profile=main10. I added it back and its running fine now..Thanks